Error in uploading Android APK signature to MI Appstore
I am uploading my app to MI play store and getting error of app verification. and I have been asked to upload the Signature as Empty Apk signed with same keystore. I followed the instructions and generated the e signature by CMD. and then I uploaded the signature and got the error for not validity.


I have tried and followed the instruction provided here https://global.developer.mi.com/document?doc=appManagement.emptyPackageSignatureGuide
but still getting error while uploading the signature apk file to store.

Do you use an already exiting keystore or have you create a new one? If it is the latter how have you crate dit (commands)?

I tried by both ways. by old keystore and also by making a new one for this. both ways give same error...
